# How do we call the 3rd group of verbs in Japanese?

Tags: translation

Japanese language have 3 groups of verbs nowadays and they are called

> - GROUP #1 = 五段動詞
> - GROUP #2 = 一段動詞
> - GROUP #3 = "Irregular Verbs"

I realised that in the past were two other groups but in a modern japanese class how do they called the irregular verbs in japanese 来る and する?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are the verb classes called ichidan and godan?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18585/why-are-the-verb-classes-called-ichidan-and-godan)

Comment: That post doesn't answer my question, sorry

Comment: That post states clearly: irregular verbs are called irregular verbs. I'm not sure what you want in addition,

Comment: I remember learning that する is サ行変格活用動詞 and くる is カ行変格活用動詞 or something like that. See here: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/活用#.E6.96.87.E8.AA.9E.E4.BD.93

Answer (score 2):

> 来る＝カ行変格活用動詞
>
> する＝サ行変格活用動詞

Quoted from the **Sweeper**'s comment above.

Comment: You should have community-wiki it, then.

Comment: Hi, l'électeur, thank you for your comment. What is community-wiki?　可能なら日本語で教えていただけますか。どうすると良かったとおっしゃっているのですか。私もSweeperさんの手柄を横取りしてポイントをもらうのは恐縮ですが、Unansweredにいつまでも残るのもどうかな、と思って、回答を書いた次第です。「引用した」ことを明記して。

Comment: @Seesawscene ちょうど Bump されていたのを見かけたので． Community wiki にする，というのは簡単には回答をコミュニティのものとして公開することです． ポイントが投稿者に入らなくなるほか，[権限があれば投稿者以外でも承認なしに編集できる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) ようになります．回答（や回答の編集）をしようとするときに，入力欄の下の Furigana/Japanese extension help » の右の方にある，あまり目立たない "community wiki" というチェックボックスに印を入れるとそうすることができます．

Comment: @Yosh：　お知らせいただきありがとうございました。今度はBumpとはなんだろうかと次から次に疑問がでます。アップボートしていただくとうれしいけれども、わけもわからずダウンボートされると意気消沈いたします。ここはなにか「せちがらい」感じがして、しばらく敬遠しようと思っていました。Yoshさんのような好意的なコメントをいただくととてもうれしいです。また復帰するようなことがありましたら、いろいろ教えてください。

Comment: @Seesawscene ややこしい言葉の説明にややこしい言葉を使ってしまいました，すみません（ちなみに bump で言おうとしたのは，upvoteないし承認された回答がない質問が時々トップページに，  Community♦ という特別なユーザが編集したのと似た状態で上がってくることです）．確かにダウンボート入れるときにはコメントとかで理由を指摘して欲しいですよね．概していえばそんなに厳しいひとばかりでもないと思うので，あまり気負わずに，お気軽に距離をとったり帰ったりしてきてくださればと思います．